# Error when building fluent_ui on flutter 3.8.0

Tags: flutter, fluent, fluent-ui

I am new to flutter and have been trying to use the fluent_ui package without success. My packages are added correctly and my main.dart file picks the fluent package but I get a weird long error when building the project.

> ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-3.9.1/lib/src/controls/form/selection_controls.dart(26,29): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'clipboardStatus' of the method '_FluentTextSelectionControls.buildToolbar' has type 'ClipboardStatusNotifier', which does not match the corresponding type, 'ClipboardStatusNotifier?', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionControls.buildToolbar'. [C:\Users\juanb\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-3.9.1/lib/src/controls/form/text_box.dart(31,35): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'details' of the method '_TextBoxSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp' has type 'TapUpDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragUpDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp'. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-3.9.1/lib/src/controls/form/text_box.dart(47,42): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'details' of the method '_TextBoxSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDragSelectionEnd' has type 'DragEndDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragEndDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDragSelectionEnd'. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-3.9.1/lib/src/controls/form/text_box.dart(41,25): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'TapUpDetails' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TapDragUpDetails'. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Compilaci�n personalizada de "C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\CMakeFiles\39bb34ccd2a2d63cfc27b36bad2cfc61\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\CMakeFiles\be203ab2df29ff02ede16a6967f51054\flutter_assemble.rule" terminada con el c�digo 1. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectos flutter\fluent_test\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> Exception: Build process failed.

I will show my flutter version, my dependencies "pubspec.yaml" file and the "main.dart" file.

#### My flutter version

> Flutter 3.8.0-17.0.pre.4 • channel main • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision 5ce4f80eeb (5 days ago) • 2023-02-25 04:23:38 -0500
> Engine • revision ddfd3dce13
> Tools • Dart 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-272.0.dev) • DevTools 2.22.1

#### My pubspec.yaml file

```
name: fluent_test
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0-272.0.dev <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  fluent_ui: ^3.9.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

#### My main.dart file

```
import 'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FluentApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: The latest stable version of Flutter is 3.7.6. You appear to be on the master channel since the version you say you are using is newer than even the latest on the beta channel. As such, compatibility errors like this are not just common, they are expected. The easiest fix is to simply switch to the stable channel.

Comment: @Abion47 you are right. it was due to the version of flutter. After downgrading to 3.7.6 it worked fine. Thanks!